# Ionic 2 CamScanner Plugin

Tags: ionic2

i want to use cordova-camscanner in my ionic 2 project. But i cant import the Plugin. [cordova-camscanner](https://github.com/Beelphegor/cordova-camscanner)

I install it with:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-camscanner --variable ANDROID_APP_KEY=YOUR_APP_KEY
```

I see the Plugin in my list with:

```
ionic plugin list
```

But when i want to import ist  with:

```
import {CordovaCamscanner} from 'ionic-native';
```

ionic says:

> node_modules/ionic-native/dist/es5/index"' has no exported member 'CordovaCamscanner'

whats wrong?

Comment: I dont think it is included in `ionic-native` http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/

Comment: i try `declare let CordovaCamscanner: any;` but result is: Uncaught ReferenceError: CordovaCamscanner is not defined

Comment: Then the result is: `cannot find name 'declare'` :-(

Comment: ok ..my bad you need `let` there

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [Ionic Native's documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/), you can see that the CamScanner plugin is not part of it (not in the list on the left side).
So

```
import {CordovaCamscanner} from 'ionic-native';
```

is not supposed to work, because as the displayed error says, it is not an exported member of the Ionic Native module.